# To Upgrade ... "Promocii" or "Altgrandigi" or

Tags: single-word-requests

About upgrading a software, an application, or a system, in Esperanto, do we say,

- [promocii](https://vortaro.net/#promocii),
- [altgradigi](https://vortaro.net/#altgrada),
- or something better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For computer related terms [Komputeko](https://komputeko.net/index_eo.php) is a good place to begin with. You can search there by English terms.

Of course there are the general dictionaries of [PIV](http://vortaro.net/) and [Reta Vortaro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/), but these ,especially the former, lack very specific words.

There are two things worth noting here. Firstly what is understood by an upgrade can vary from company to company. Secondly to avoid cultural-based misunderstandings Esperanto uses often quite concrete expressions, much more than English. Given these you have to little decipher, what an "upgrade" in your context means.

Usually an update, *ĝisdatigo* or *aktualigo*, improves existing features or add new ones without an extra charge.

For an upgrade you usually have to pay. An upgrade can be just a prolongation of some period (say, from a one year service plan to a three years plan), so it's essentially *daŭrigo*.

If you get extra features, whether these are better service (e.g. you get a faster response) or new features (e.g. additional filters in an image manipulation application), you get a new, upgraded edition of the software. So you get *promocian eldonon* or *plibonigan eldonon* with the nuance difference, that the former is more suitable for something non-tangible (e.g. service) and the later for something more concrete (e.g. new features).

Comment: Thanks Juha, superb explanation.

Comment: I'd go with _ĝisdatigo_ or _aktualigo_, **not** _daŭrigo_ (time extension).

Comment: @vesperto, I would not call an offer "Upgrade your one year service plan now to a three years plan for only xx" a _ĝisdatigo_ or _aktualigo_. In other words decipher, what an "upgrade" in a given context means.

Answer (score 2):

*Ĝisdatigi*. Tiajn tradukojn i povas serĉi ĉi tie ekzemple: https://transvision.mozfr.org/

*Update/Upgrade* estas tre ofte tradukitaj per la sama vorto, ankaŭ en aliaj lingvoj. Vidu ekzemple [Update](https://transvision.mozfr.org/string/?entity=browser/chrome/browser/browser.properties:webextPerms.updateAccept.label&repo=gecko_strings) kaj [Upgrade](https://transvision.mozfr.org/string/?entity=browser/installer/custom.properties:UPGRADE_BUTTON&repo=gecko_strings) en Mozilla.

Comment: How does that add any information that wasn't given in Juha's answer?

Comment: I added another source for technical translations and gave some information and additional links on the fact that most languages use the same word for upgrade/update. I don't think it deserves the downvote (before asking). Also Juha's answer mentions things that are inaccurate (say for Firefox, where yo never pay for upgrade/update) and I never heard of _promoci/_ en tiu kunteksto. It felt off-topic to discuss those issues. So I answered just what the OP asked with the additional references.

Comment: Of course you don't pay for an update or upgrade of free software. Upgrade and update are different things (even though for Firefox it might be the same - they don't update older versions if there is a free new one) and imo Juha explains that pretty clear and accurate. Ĝistatigi is also mentioned in Juha's answer. OP is asking for a translation of *upgrade*. Saying *just use update, it's the same in many languages* is not a good answer imho and I doubt that it's true. Google translate gives different translations for all languages that I checked.

Comment: I guess all those community teams of translators got it wrong and Google translates it right :). Mozilla does not use automatic translation, it's always teams, and some of them, like the French team even have professional translators. German, French, Russian, Spanish, Italian, ... they use the same word for those two standalone Upgrade/Update strings. It's not a matter of belief, just a fact on the other side of the links, if you care to follow them. But I can now understand your downvote. Thanks for explaining it.

Comment: Check community driven [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc) then. As I said, for Firefox it doesn't make much sense to differentiate between update and upgrade. That doesn't mean, there is no difference in general.